# How can I disable a model field in a django form

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I have a model like this:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    REGULAR = 1
    PREMIUM = 2
    STATUS_CHOICES = ((REGULAR, "regular"), (PREMIUM, "premium"))
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    status = models.IntegerField(choices = STATUS_CHOICES, default = REGULAR)

class MyForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = models.MyModel
```

In a view I initialize one field and try to make it non-editable:

```
myform = MyForm(initial = {'status': requested_status})
myform.fields['status'].editable = False
```

But the user can still change that field.

What's the real way to accomplish what I'm after?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

**Step 1: Disable the frontend widget**

Use the HTML `readonly` attribute:
http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_readonly.asp

Or `disabled` attribute:
http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#adef-disabled

You can inject arbitrary HTML key value pairs via the widget attrs property:

```
myform.fields['status'].widget.attrs['readonly'] = True # text input
myform.fields['status'].widget.attrs['disabled'] = True # radio / checkbox
```

**Step 2: Ensure the field is effectively disabled on backend**

Override your clean method for your field so that regardless of POST input (somebody can fake a POST, edit the raw HTML, etc.) you get the field value that already exists.

```
def clean_status(self):
    # when field is cleaned, we always return the existing model field.
    return self.instance.status
```

Comment: Oh no. I tried it, and `readonly` doesn't make a difference. And (http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_readonly.asp) says 'The readonly attribute can be used with <input type="text"> or <input type="password">.' In my case it's a select or radio buttons. So any more ideas?

Comment: Hmm, looks like the solution with those buttons is attrs['disabled'] = True http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#adef-disabled

Comment: Works just the way I wanted. Thank you!

Comment: No problem jammon. If you found it satisfactory, check the checkmark next to the answer.

Comment: I get the error: `'BoundField' object has no attribute 'widget'`

Comment: How i can select all fields?

Comment: for selecting all fields:

for key in self.fields.keys():
                self.fields[key].widget.attrs['readonly'] = True
                self.fields[key].widget.attrs['disabled'] = True

Comment: I was missing the clean part to maintain the value.  A lifesaver, thanks!

Answer (score 12):

From django 1.9:

```
from django.forms import Textarea

class MyModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields = '__all__'
        widgets = {'my_field_in_my_model': Textarea(attrs={'cols':80,'rows':1}),}             

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['my_field_in_my_model'].disabled = True
```

Answer (score 8):

Have you tried using the exclude function?

something like this

```
class PartialAuthorForm(ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = Author
    fields = ('name', 'title')

class PartialAuthorForm(ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = Author
    exclude = ('birth_date',)
```

[Reference Here](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/)

Comment: I wanted to alter the form _per instance_, so `exclude` doesn't do the trick for me.

Comment: @jammon: (1) "per instance" doesn't make sense. You can have several different subclasses with several different combinations of fields. (2) Please **update** the question to explain what you want.

Answer (score 4):

Just customize the widget instance for the status field:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    REGULAR = 1
    PREMIUM = 2
    STATUS_CHOICES = ((REGULAR, "regular"), (PREMIUM, "premium"))
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    status = models.IntegerField(choices = STATUS_CHOICES, default = REGULAR)

class MyForm(forms.ModelForm):
    status =  forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'readonly':'True'}))

    class Meta:
        model = models.MyModel
```

see: [Django Documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/forms/widgets/#styling-widget-instances)

Answer (score 4):

There is a very easy way of doing it:

```
class GenerateCertificate(models.Model):

    field_name = models.CharField(
        max_length=15,
        editable=False)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return unicode(self.field_name)
```

The `editable=False` will make the field disabled for editing.