# Setting the initial value for a readonly Choice (ForeignKey) field

Tags: django, forms, django-forms

I'm trying to make a CreateView have a readonly field with a set value, but I'm unable to make that work.

I have a model with a ForeignKey to another model:

```
class CompanyNote(TimeStampedModel):
    company = models.ForeignKey(Company)
    note = models.TextField(blank=True)
```

And I have a CreateView:

```
class CompanyNoteCreateView(CreateView):
    model = models.CompanyNote
    form_class = CompanyNoteForm
```

That uses a custom ModelForm:

```
class CompanyNoteForm(forms.ModelForm):

    company = forms.ChoiceField(
        widget=forms.widgets.Select(attrs={'readonly': 'readonly'}))

    class Meta:
        model = models.CompanyNote
```

As you see, the widget for the field in question is readonly. This is because I pick up the company as a part of the URL, as in `company/1/note/add` . I have no trouble picking up the "1" and finding the right company object, but I don't know how to set the readonly field.

I tried:

```
def get_initial(self):
    initial = super(CompanyNoteCreateView, self).get_initial()
    initial['company'] = self.get_company().id
    return initial
```

But that didn't work. The Widget is empty, which may be the problem. Perhaps I'm barking up the wrong tree here. Any ideas welcome.

Comment: Have you tried setting `choices` in your widget?

Comment: @drewman: As the choices are dynamic, that wouldn't work. But the solution to that is the ModelChoiceField mentioned by Nathaniel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried setting the attribute in the Form's Meta class?

I experienced an issue where Form attributes were not applied for Model Fields if set in the base class definition, but they worked correctly in the Meta class:

```
class CompanyNoteForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = models.CompanyNote
        widgets = {'company': forms.widgets.Select(attrs={'readonly': True,
                                                          'disabled': True})}
```

Otherwise check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/325038/1998376) out.

Worst case scenario, make company a hidden field?

Comment: It also solves the initial value problem, and it's slightly "cleaner" than setting the form field, so this is a good solution. The widget is still not actually read only, so I still need a ReadOnlySelectWidget, and also to make the field read-only as per other questions and answers.

Comment: For a `Select` you need to set also the `disabled` attribute as specified in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4945913/1935366)

Answer (score 1):

Use a `ModelChoiceField`

```
class CompanyNoteForm(forms.ModelForm):
    company = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=models.Company.objects.all(), widget=forms.widgets.Select(attrs={'readonly': 'readonly'}))
```

Comment: That works, in as much that I can now set the initial value. Funnily enough, it's not read_only though (neither in Firefox nor in Chrome). It *looks* readonly, and Firefox even shows a little "Not allowed" mouse pointer. But it's not readonly...

Comment: It might remove it altogether, but what if you add to `class Meta:` an exclude of `exclude = ('company',)` I'm not able to try this right now so it might remove the company altogether.

Comment: Weirdly enough that just moves the field to the bottom of the form. I think it gets added back since it's required. I'll probably override the SelectWidget to handle readonly more sensibly.

Answer (score 0):

I could not find this answer anywhere, that I could actually get to work. But I found a different approach. Set the field to be hidden with forms.HiddenInput() widget. Then the value you pass in from the view will be assigned but the user cannot access it.

```
widgets = {'field_name': forms.HiddenInput()}
```

I'm using ModelForm class so my syntax might be different from yours.