# How can I make a disable field with modelform after django 1.9

Tags: django, python-3.x

I'd like to create disabled field with ModelForm on django 1.11.

I read django has "disabled field options" since 1.9.
However, I can not understand how do I define disabled field with ModelForm.

Could you tell me how to create disabled field with ModelForm please ?

Here is my models.py, forms.py and views.py

---

```
class my_model(models.Model)

    name = models.CharField(max_length=10,)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=10,)
    date = models.DateField(default=date.today,)

    def __str__(self):
        return u'%s' % (self.name)

class my_modelform(ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = my_model
        fields = ['name', 'title', 'date']
        widgets = {
            'date': DateWidget(usel10n=True, bootstrap_version=3,),
        }
        disabled = [ 'name' ]

class my_UpdateView(UpdateView):
    model = my_model
    form_class = my_modelform
    template_name = "update_form.html"
    success_url = "success.html"
```

---

Although, I changed the "disabled = {'name' : True} instead of [ 'name' ], it doesn't work.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4945913/2896976

Comment: This question is not same as your marked question, because django version is different. The answer did not show an example code on Djano 1.9 or later.

Answer (score 18):

```
class Meta:
    model = my_model
    fields = ['name', 'title', 'date']
    widgets = {
        'date': DateWidget(usel10n=True, bootstrap_version=3,),
        'name': forms.TextInput(attrs={'disabled': True}),
    }
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I did it

Comment: Glad I could help. If the answer helped you, mark it as accepted and happy coding!

Comment: It worked, but the disabled options filed will miss the value when I submit.

Comment: Of course it will miss it since it is disabled! How you pass that value?

Comment: Oh, I thought "disable" means that the field can not edit. not remove the column.
 
My goal is that there is only one or two field can be editable when I use UpdateView.
Therefore, I want the rest fields switch uneditable field.

Comment: If I understand correclty, what you asked is feasible via Javascript. The original question was to make a `ModelForm` field, `disabled`.

Comment: Yes, the original question is "Make a disabled field with ModelForm"  I should have asked that what I want to do, because the feature did not same as that I thought.... I really appreciate your great help.

Comment: Hmm. Then glad once again I could help. In your next question be more specific please!

Comment: I changed "attrs={'readonly': True}" instead of "attrs={'disabled': True}", then it works as expected.

Comment: That's great news! Although your question asked another thing... Anyway, take care my friend.

Comment: This is awesome, works for all sorts of field. Also works for enforcing all type of inputfield