# Django admin: Making a required field read-only

Tags: django, django-admin

I have a number of models with a ForeignKey relationship to a `Person` model.  For example:

```
class PersonData(BaseModel):
    person = models.ForeignKey(Person)
    data = models.TextField()
```

I want to lock down the admin such that once a `PersonData` object is created, an admin user can change the data, but can't change the `Person`.

At first it seemed pretty straightforward -- I put this in the `PersonDataAdmin` class:

```
def get_readonly_fields(self, request, obj=None):
    if obj:
        return self.readonly_fields + ('person',)
    return self.readonly_fields
```

On the display side, that worked as expected -- I see the value for `person`, but it's grayed out so I can't change it -- but then when I try to change the data and submit the form, I get an error message, "Please correct the error below."  No other message appears, but with a bit of digging, I discovered that the form is missing a value for the required `person` field.

I've investigated a solution that would involve creating a custom form that would disable this field selectively (something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/324477/in-a-django-form-how-do-i-make-a-field-readonly-or-disabled-so-that-it-cannot) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4945802/how-can-i-disable-a-model-field-in-a-django-form)), but (a) I wasn't successful in getting it to work, and (b) it seemed like a ton of code for what seems like a much simpler situation.  I also looked into using `exclude`, but ran into the same problem as `read_only`.

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: you can use readonly_fields in django admin

Comment: My question is more complicated than that.

Answer (score 35):

What I usually do is set the field in the model as `editable=False` and then in the admin.py set the field as read-only like this,

```
class PersonData(BaseModel):
    person = models.ForeignKey(Person, editable=False)
    data = models.TextField()
```

Then in admin.py

```
class PersonDataAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    readonly_fields=('person',)
```

Hope this works!

Comment: That doesn't work in this case, since the field is editable half the time.

Comment: settings a model field as `editable=False` won't show it on the Admin and skip validation. 
The read_only field does the job. 
Ref: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/fields/#editable

Answer (score 5):

I hit the same problem. A workaround is to define a method in the Admin class that returns the value of the readonly field that you want to display. Then use the name of the method where you would previously have used the name of the field.
e.g. rather than:

```
class PersonDataAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    readonly_fields=('person',)
```

use:

```
class PersonDataAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    readonly_fields=('person_method',)

    def person_method(self, obj):
        return obj.person

    person_method.short_description = 'Person'
```

The short_description sets the label for the field. If you don't set it then the field will be labelled as "Person method"

Presumably in the OPs case get_readonly_fields becomes:

```
def get_readonly_fields(self, request, obj=None):
    if obj:
        return self.readonly_fields + ('person_method',)
    return self.readonly_fields
```

Comment: Using only `get_readonly_fields` from this answer does the trick on non-method-sourced (normal) field. Not sure how the whole answer would work - method-sourced fields are read only anyway.

Answer (score 3):

You could extend `ModelAdmin.get_form()` and use [Field.disabled](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/forms/fields/#disabled) to disable the `person` field, as follows:

```py
def get_form(self, request, obj=None, change=False, **kwargs):
    form = super().get_form(request, obj, change, **kwargs)
    if obj:
        form.base_fields['person'].disabled = True
    return form
```

This will prevent the `person` field from being modified.

However, it will still be styled as a select box, and it may still have the "change" and "add another" buttons next to it.

These buttons are added by the [RelatedFieldWidgetWrapper](https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/3.2.x/django/contrib/admin/widgets.py#L224). One way to remove them is by removing the wrapper:

```py
...
field = form.base_fields['person']
field.disabled = True
if isinstance(field.widget, RelatedFieldWidgetWrapper):
    # unwrap the widget
    field.widget = field.widget.widget
```

Another way is to set the following widget attributes:

```py
...
if isinstance(field.widget, RelatedFieldWidgetWrapper):
    field.widget.can_add_related = False
    field.widget.can_change_related = False
```

If you want the field to be styled as a `readonly` field, you'll need some extra work. Also see the [fieldset.html](https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/3.2.x/django/contrib/admin/templates/admin/includes/fieldset.html#L17) template and [AdminReadonlyField](https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/3.2.x/django/contrib/admin/helpers.py#L233) to understand how django admin displays foreign-key `readonly_fields`.

Another approach altogether would be to implement your own `ReadOnlyWidget`, similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15134622), and just set  `form.base_fields['person'].widget = ReadOnlyWidget()`

Answer (score 2):

Here's [ModelAdmin.readonly_fields](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.readonly_fields) documentation.

Answer (score 2):

**field1** is a required field here and it is made as **read only** in admin screen

#### model.py

```
class ModelName(models.Model):
  field1 = models.ForeignKey(
      ModelA, 
      on_delete=models.CASCADE,
      db_column='col1',
      related_name='col1',
      verbose_name='col1'
  )
  field2 = models.ForeignKey(
      ModelB, 
      on_delete=models.CASCADE,
      db_column='col2',
      related_name='col2',
      verbose_name='col2'
  )
```

#### admin.py

```
    @admin.register(ModelName)
    class AdminClassName(admin.ModelAdmin):
        fields = ('field1', 'field2')
        readonly_fields = ('field1')
```

Answer (score 1):

> In Django - 4.1.3

```
from django.contrib import admin
from app.models import User

class UserAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
   readonly_fields = ['last_login']

admin.site.register(User, UserAdmin)
```

[If you want to make fields read-only for specific users](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74565069/11510952)

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem of yours. Check if you are using get_form on your admin class. Somehow this was the cause of my problem.